# Angular, injecting own service into provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am working with a provider and injecting some of angular's $log and $location service in the $get to work with them, and this works fine. However when I want to inject my own service into the provider it does not seem to work.

Here's what I mean - I can inject the angular $log and $location like so (in the provider)

```
   this.$get = $get;
    $get.$inject = ['$log', '$location'];

    function $get( $log, $location) {
        return {
            setModule: function(name, cb) {

            },
            getModules: function() {

            }
        }
    }
```

But, I have a service below like

```
 .service("myService",function(){
 this.sayHello = function() {
    return "Hello, World!"
});
```

And try to inject it like

```
 $get.$inject = ['myService', '$log', '$location'];

    function $get(myService, $log, $location) {
```

When I call myService in the provider, it comes back undefined.

Is there any reason I can call the angular($) stuff and not my own to inject into the provider?

Thanks!

Edit : So after I inject it I try and use it inside the $get like

```
   $get.$inject = ['myService', '$log', '$location'];

    function $get(myService, $log, $location) {
      return {
          test: function(){
               console.log(myService);
           }
        }
```

returns undefined

Comment: you can, and that syntax looks correct.  What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Claies when I call myService.sayHello, it's saying myService is undefined (in the provider)

Comment: @Claies  here I dropped it in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yz9spfob/1/

Comment: @Alex, how you check that `myService` is _undefined_, i small change your fiddle, but seems that all work: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz9spfob/2/)

Comment: @Grundy sorry i didnt drop everything in there just the code around it, it would have to be called, I can try and whip up a fiddle with it working

Comment: @Alex are you try [changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yz9spfob/2/)?

Answer (score 0):

1) pass $injector as a dependency in the controller ['$injector']

2) call $injector.get to instantiate the service by name

$scope.service = $injector.get(servicename);

Comment: How does this work in the provider? I'm not passing this to a controller.

Comment: haven't tried with a provider but I assume you can pass the $injector as a dependency to the Provider as well.